# How can I draw Polygons on google-maps with coordinates from Array

Tags: java, android

I retrieved Coordinates from firestore and saved them in a latlng list array.

Then using a for loop, i had the elements in the list array populated in an PolygonOptions Variable.
Debugging shows that all the data is where it is supposed to be but am not able to draw the polygon on the map

Here is what i tried

```
 private void DrawPolygon(List<LatLng> array) {

    int length = array.size();
    if(length == 0)
    {
        // Do whatever you like then get out. Do not run the following.
        return;
    } 
    PolygonOptions poly = new PolygonOptions();
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            LatLng latLong = new LatLng(array.get(i).latitude,
                    array.get(i).longitude);
            poly.add(latLong);
        }
        Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(poly);
```

`

The app does not show any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
poly.strokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

poly.fillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,android.R.color.holo_orange_light));
```

Comment: Its still not drawing anything

Comment: you have added these lines before mMap.addPolygon(poly);. Could i ask why are you returning mMap.addPolygon(poly)

Comment: From the code i posted, You can see that poly is populated with coordinates from the perimeter array. So returning mMap.addPolygon(poly) should draw the polygon on the map

Comment: if i was to manually add each of the coordinates like usual with the `polygonOptions().add ( new latlng .. `, the above snippet woud work. but i cant do that as they are stored in a firestore database and are retrieved and stored in an array which is passed to the DrawPolygon method as a perimeter

Comment: did you update the map camera after the values are returned

Comment: sorry for the last comment , the comment prior to it didnt load, okay so you are adding these values from firebase, and its working `polygonOptions().add ( new latlng .. ` in this format, just give me a minute

Comment: okay what you do is dont use a for loop, instead use `  PolygonOptions poly = new PolygonOptions();
 poly.addAll(array);
        
 Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(poly); `

Comment: It still does not draw

Comment: It's working for me, maybe try converting array (list) to arraylist

Comment: is your array a list of locations or latlng??? because i am using arraylist of latlng, then use the above code

Comment: My arraylist is for latlng

Comment: i used  `{  List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
        latLngs.add(new LatLng(26.875749, 80.949827));
        latLngs.add(new LatLng(26.873060, 80.955849));
        latLngs.add(new LatLng(26.860017, 80.959198));

        DrawPolygon(latLngs);


    }

    private void DrawPolygon(List<LatLng> latLngs) {

        PolygonOptions poly = new PolygonOptions();
        poly.addAll(latLngs);
        Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(poly);
    }`

Comment: I think the problem comes from the array that stores the coordinates.

Comment: Yes I was also thinking that, if possible why don't you try converting your List to arraylist

Comment: I did  but it still failed

Comment: Here is what i used for retrieving the data `if (task.isSuccessful()){DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoint = (ArrayList<GeoPoint>) document.get(s);
                            ArrayList<LatLng>points = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i=0; i < geoPoint.size(); i++){
                                Double lat = geoPoint.get(i).getLatitude();Double lng = geoPoint.get(i).getLatitude();points.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));}DrawPolygon(points);
                        }`

Comment: I would have posted the whole method but commenting has a character limit. The above code is from a search method with String variable `s` as a parameter

Comment: Okay just try log/print the the list from firebase, just to check if the values are coming up right.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I already did that and they are coming out right

Comment: I completely didnot notice that i was calling getlatitude() twice from firebase. Thanks for your help